# Locked/stuck up screensaver after monitor turns off

Tags: screensaver, logout

Since I started using Natty I experience a strange situation at times. When I leave my system idle for 30+ mins., the screensaver **Ant Spotlight** remains active for specified time, then the monitor turns off after a while. Later when I am back to work on moving mouse/pressing keys on keyboard monitor powers on but I am greeted with a stuck up *Ant* in the screen. I won't be able to access open applications in any way. No key/mouse click works. I tried going to terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F1 and killing gnome-screensav but the *Ant* doesn't budge. Only way out I take is to log out with Ctrl+Alt+Backspace which works causing to lose my unsaved work.

Comment: Does this happen with any other screensaver?

Comment: Didn't really try. In fact Ant Spotlight is my favorite. Also I must tell that it doesn't happen every time.

Comment: What GPU do you have?

Comment: I have the Intel onboard 256 MB GPU.

Comment: This seems to be [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/762918) or [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/780653) bug. I just tried enabling "Lock screen when screensave is active" in gnome-screensaver-preferences, and it worked at least once now, i.e. I had to type my password but the screen was not blank with only the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem on mine... does the same thing with GLMatrix.

At first I thought the problem was maybe due to using encrypted home directory, and since that was causing me grief in other ways I re-installed sans encryption.  Still have the same problem.

Only fix so far that I've found is to turn off the screensaver.

Answer (score 1):

The trick that helped for me was to go to the text-only terminal and then immediately back to the GUI, that is: first press CTRL+ALT+F1 and then CTRL+ALT+F7. This does not do anything about the cause of the problem but allows you to start using the GUI again.